# Listview onItemClick sometimes not responding

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and a custom adapter.

on my list view I set this :

lv.setOnItemClickListener(...)

All is working fine. But When I start scrolling it doesn't. While I scroll down slowly it is stable (onItemClick is called) but when I scroll down more quickly or scroll down & up several times quickly,  selecting an item do not fire an event. But if I wait a little or keep clicking an item or slowly scroll to the top, it randomly works.

Sometimes when I click an item it displays the yellow background (and onItemClick not called).
Sometimes the orange background stay even after I stop touching (and onItemClick not called).
Sometimes the background don't change at all (and onItemClick not called).
And sometimes it works.

The items of the list are made of several textView / imageview / linearlayout (I set for each focusable=false it changed nothing) dynamically inflated with a view holder.

Do someone has an idea of what is wrong or have an idea how to debug it ?

(The source code is too big to be pasted here, I can send you the source code or the apk if you wish)

Comment: Could you please provide some code? It is hard to diagnose a problem if the code producing it cannot be seen.

Comment: Are you adjusting the interactivity parameters of the views for any reason (selectable/clickable/focusable/enabled)?  You shouldn't have to do this and doing so can cause very strange results.  If you can't post the Activity code here, put it into something like Pastebin or put the code in a public repo somewhere like Github so we can analyze it.  Cheers.

Comment: for the fast scrolls problem, you're probably reaching the bottom/top and you're on Android 2.2. It has a bug in `Scroller` class for which it won't "stop" scrolling, so you need to wait for it to "consume" its momentum or click once to "stop" it (it's not a visible thing), before being able to click the contents. It happens in `ScrollViews` too.

Comment: Here is the code main activity code http://pastebin.com/pZ1qbyRg

Comment: Hi @jpprade, did you find a solution to this? (So long ago, I know). I discovered that my custom `ListView` only long clicks on my 2nd `TextView`, but not my first (don't know why), independent of any of the solutions I add from answers below. Works perfectly for the 2nd, but never works for the first, and they are supposed to be in a single item spot in the `ListView`, so it's puzzling how to get it all to long click. User won't know to only click on the 2nd one. :/

Comment: This was on android 2.x, now its getting better, but I think the problem was that I was doing too mush work in the adapter. There is lot of tutoriel nowadays explaining how to recycle view, and cache TextView, to avoid doing a findviewbyid. Maybe the ScrollView bug was not helping too.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to you parent layout of listview custom row xml file
**android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

Also
in the textview of your inflator(Custom row view) layout just add:

android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My ListView items consisted of a LinearLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView. In addition to the following for my layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and the following for my TextView and ImageView, as suggested in another answer:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

I also added this this to my ImageView:

```
android:clickable="false"
```